# TagLib - How to handle UTF-8 encoded file paths?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, unicode, taglib

Problem: I want TagLib::FileRef to open a file with Unicode characters in its file name or path, but do not succeed.

I compiled TagLib 1.7 with MinGW (GNU Make 3.81, GCC 4.4.0) under Windows 7 (64-bit, but 32-bit compiler) after creating the Makefile with CMake 2.8.4. I use TagLib in conjunction with the Qt 4.7.2 framework.

For interchanging strings between the two libraries, TagLib provides:

```
#define QStringToTString(s) TagLib::String(s.toUtf8().data(), TagLib::String::UTF8)
#define TStringToQString(s) QString::fromUtf8(s.toCString(true))
// toUtf8() is a fix, originally spelled utf8(), but that's not relevant here.
```

I constructed TagLib::FileRef as follows:

```
TagLib::FileRef fileRef( QStringToTString(filePath).toCString(true) );
// or:
TagLib::FileRef fileRef( TagLib::FileName( QStringToTString(filePath).toCString(true) ) );
```

As a result, files with paths containing Unicode characters or Latin-1 characters with a different code in the UTF-8 representation (f.ex. umlauts or chinese characters) fail to load (fileRef.isNull()).

If I pass *false* to the function toCString() above (declaration: see below), TagLib can handle umlauts (but not Unicode-only characters). Therefore I guess I have compiled TagLib wrongly (TagLib::FileRef interpretes the given string as Latin-1), but I don't know how to check or even correct this. Note: Unicode strings in (ID3) tags are retrieved correctly with TagLib.

toCString():

```
const char* TagLib::String::toCString( bool unicode = false ) const;
```

Doc: [TagLib documentation](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib/api/annotated.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileRef` constructor accepts a `FileName` object (not `String`!), which can be either `char*` or `wchar_t*` string. On Windows you can assume that both `wchar_t` and `QChar` have 16-bits, so you can simply pass it `filePath.constData()`.

Note that if you are planning to run the code on non-Windows platform, you need to have an `#ifdef` check around the `FileRef` object creation, because on other platforms it only accepts `char*` strings and you should use `QFile::encodeName(filePath).constData()`.

Comment: Thanks, `TagLib::FileRef fileRef( reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(filePath.constData()) );` works well under Windows. I'm planning to run that on different systems; will `QFile::encodeName()` probably UTF-8 encode this?

Comment: Yes, most other systems use UTF-8 filenames now, but it will usually depend on the user's settings, so you can't assume it will be UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to is to use `toStdString()` followed by `c_str()`.

```
QString path(...);
std::string stdString = path.toStdString();
const char *cPath = stdString.c_str();
TagLib::FileRef fr(cPath);
```

Make sure to store the stdString as a variable, as without that it will be destroyed by the end of the line.

At least in my case, both `QFile::encodeName(filePath)` and `QString::toLocal8Bit()` failed - it replaced `ąęóżłćĄĘŁ` with `aeózlcAEL` (looks like `ó` was lucky enough to survive that), which caused my application to crash. Unfortunately I am unable to answer why the Qt methods didn't work in my case.